# Qualifying bulk copy table mappings MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I was wondering if there was a way to qualify the table mappings when using `sqlbulkcopy` in c#?

Currently, I have a table that contains Stock Codes and then columns associated with range of weekly bucks.

example:

```
Stock Code | 11-2013 | 12-2013| 13-2013 | 14-2013 etc etc.
```

I have a query that returns quantities for the given stock code and the week number in which they occurred.

example:

```
part a | 20 | 11-2013

part b | 10 | 14-2013
```

Ideally, there would be a way to set the `columnmappings.add` method and specify that I would like to map the date column of the table to the resulting date in the return row of the query. I would show what I have; however, I have no idea if this is even possible. Any suggestions or alternative ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You can specific column mappings by name. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: You would have to do this yourself.  I.E, read the source data rows and create target datarows filling up the columns and then submit to SQLBulkCopy as they were ready.

Comment: What you *CAN* do is to change your source query to pivot the rows into columns for you.  Assuming that your source is SQL Server or some other SQL DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly possible. Your source data has to match to your destination data. The `SqlBulkCopy` class isn't going to do that for you.

Create a sql query from your source data that matches the table schema of your destination table. Then you can use the `SqlBulkCopy` class.